# where i can download google earth api for asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-earth

I want to create a web application with Google earth. But i can't download the asp.net Google Earth API. Is there is any way to create a Google earth application? Please give some idea to create this application.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? What have you tried? Docs look pretty self explanatory https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/index

Comment: Did you really tried to download google API ??

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this, it worked for me

http://www.searchengineknowledge.com/hosting/embedgooglemaps.php

Comment: Please don't post a link without a summary or explanation of what it contains. We do expect a little bit of effort around here. Perhaps a pretty codesnippet, a short summary, something like that. =)

Comment: I need Google Earth not Google Map..